# If I have Family Share enabled, can we play two different games at the same time?

Tags: steam

If I'm playing Rocket League on my account and he's playing Skyrim which is on my account too, can we play at the same time?

Answer (score 5):

No you can't. If he is playing Skyrim, and you just start up Rocket League. He will then receive a message saying he has 5 minutes to disconnect before eventually being booted off.  A quote from [Steam Family Sharing](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing).

**When I authorize a device to lend my library to others, do I limit my own ability to access and play my games?**

> As the account holder, you may always access and play your games at any time. If you decide to start playing when another user is already playing one of your games, he/she will be given a few minutes to either purchase the game or quit playing.